# Django Rest Framework: Error - "user with this uuid already exists."

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have written a model and made uuid as my primary id. When I use the POST it gives me error -  **"user with this uuid already exists."** This error started showing only when I changed my User's model primary key from 'id' to 'uuid'.

These are the relevant models -

User Model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_id      = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default="")
```

Appointment Model:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    zorg = models.ForeignKey(Zorg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Zorg_Branche, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='branch')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    status      = models.ForeignKey(Appointment_Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    totaltime   = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
```

Appointment Detail Model:

```
class AppointmentDetail(models.Model):
    appointment  = models.ForeignKey(Appointment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='appointment')
    service      = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name='service')
```

Relevant Serializers -

UserAppointmentSerializer:

```
class UserAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
                'uuid',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email_id',
                'mobile_number',
                'birthdate',
                'photo_url',
                'gender',
              ]

class ZorgBranchAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zorg_Branche
        exclude = ['id', 'zorg']

class ServiceAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        exclude = ['id', 'category']

class ZorgAppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Zorg
        fields = [
                'id',
                 'name',
                 'salon_email_id',
                 'website'
             ]

class AppointmentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    service = ServiceAppointmentSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = AppointmentDetail
        exclude = ['id', 'appointment']

class AppointmentStatusSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment_Status
        fields = ['status']

class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    appointment = AppointmentDetailSerializer(many=True)
    status = AppointmentStatusSerilizer()
    user = UserAppointmentSerializer()
    zorg = ZorgAppointmentSerializer()
    branch = ZorgBranchAppointmentSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['id', 'status',
            'appointment',
            'user',
            'zorg',
            'branch',
            'timestamp',
            'totaltime',
            'total_price']

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.pop('user')
    zorg = validated_data.pop('zorg')
    status = validated_data.pop('status')
    branch = validated_data.pop('branch')

    user_instance = User.objects.get(**user)
    zorg_instance = Zorg.objects.get(**zorg)
    status_instance = Appointment_Status.objects.get(**status)
    branch_instance = Zorg_Branche.objects.get(**branch)

    appointment_services = validated_data.pop('appointment')

    appointment = Appointment.objects.create(user = user_instance, zorg = zorg_instance, status = status_instance, branch = branch_instance, **validated_data)

    for services in appointment_services:
        service = services.pop('service')
        service_instance = Service.objects.get(**service)
        AppointmentDetail.objects.create(appointment=appointment, service=service_instance)

    return appointment
```

Comment: I assume this occurs when trying to create a new user. The error you're getting occurs when you try to duplicate a unique field in a `model` in this case your `primay-key`. First off if you must use a custom primary key, use an `int` that `auto-increment`s this way you don't have to worry about duplicates and keeping track of used values.

Comment: I am getting this error when I make an appointment using JSON POST. When I create using admin panel it works fine but when I use POST method for making an appointment and pass the user uuid then it happens. When I remove the uuid field from the serializer it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is whether you need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on the database.

Sounds like it could be the problem because the issue occurred after changing the model.

If that doesn't fix it, try using Django's built in UUIDField instead of CharField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

```py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # rest of your code...
```

I'd also probably recommend using Django's built-in authentication system to manage users instead.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/

Comment: I checked running the migrations commands and the migrations weren't needed. I can't use the UUIDField instead of CharField because I am passing this field in the url to get details of individual user. When I removed the uuid field from the serializer it started working fine but when I use uuid it gives me this error.